# How do I use a struct in a different file

Tags: c++, function, struct, namespaces

I have a struct S, declared in header1.h, that I need to use (as a vector) in header2.h and header2.cpp.
I believe I have followed another similar example that already exists in the code, but I still get an error, and I do not understand why.

This is basically the code:

header1.h

```
#pragma once

namespace NSP
{
struct S{
float a;
int b;
};

class KPR
{
void funfun(int a); //struct S is used in funfun
}
}
```

then I have header1.cpp

```
#include "header1.h"
using namespace KPR;
using namespace std;

void KPR::funfun(int a)
{
S thisVec;
}
```

then I have header2.h

```
#pragma once
#include "header1.h"
namespace NSP{
class header2
{
public:
header2(void);
~header2(void);
int func(NSP::S thisVec);
};
}
```

and of course header2.cpp

```
#include "anotherHeader.h"  //(a bunch of includes, amongst others #include header1.h)
header2::header2(void){
}
header2::~header2(void){
}
int header2::func(NSP::S thisVec)
{
}
```

In other words,

I have followed the structure of another input argument of func which is also a struct, but declared in its own .h file (same namespace though).
I have simplified the problem a bit by using NSP::S instead of std::vectorNSP::S
But it is the same error: at this point, there is a red squiggle below func in the cpp file and the error message window displays func(.... thisVec ...) instead of NSP::S thisVec.
I am left scratching my head as to why this happens, can someone please explain what is going on?

Comment: Change `header2::header2` to `NSP::header2::header2`. See [working demo](https://onlinegdb.com/ARaW7bBT4)

Comment: Put everything in the cpp file inside the namespace; `namespace NSP { header::header2() {} ... }`

Comment: Side note: the parameter list `(void)` is a C-ism. In C++, write `()`.

Answer (score 5):

The **problem** is that when implementing the member functions of class `NSP::header2`, you're not in the scope of namespace `NSP`. Essentially you're implementing them(incorrectly) in global namespace. In other words, if you choose to define the member functions outside the class, then they **must be implemented in the same namespace in which the class was defined**. This means they should be implemented in `NSP` and **not** global namespace.

To **solve** this replace `header2::header2` with `NSP::header2::header2` as shown below:

```
#include "header2.h" 
vvvvv------------------------->added this 
NSP::header2::header2(void){
}
vvvvv------------------------->added this
NSP::header2::~header2(void){
}
int NSP::header2::func(NSP::S thisVec)
{
}
```

[Working demo](https://onlinegdb.com/ARaW7bBT4)

Comment: I am trying this, but it seems to not be the main issue; I do not get the same error as in the working demo. Other functions (which do not use "NSP::S thisVec") in header2.cpp do work. In header2.h, the input argument struct NSP::S thisVec also has a red squiggle under "S", but there is no pop-up when hovering over it. Hovering over the red-underlined function func in .cpp shows: 
"Error: declaration not compatible with func(..., <error-type> thisVec, ...) (already declared at line 101 in header2.h)"

Comment: @sblyat Note that you're missing a semicolon `;` in file `header2.h` after the class closing brace `}`. You should add that semicolon.

Comment: It is there in the actual code, sorry for forgotting it here

Comment: @sblyat That is why it is recommended that a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) should be given. You can ask a new separate question.

Comment: @sblyat You should ask a new separate question for your follow up question with a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).